# Adding to list from hashmap key kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, hashmap

I'm practicing leetcode problems to perfect my kotlin syntax and am wondering why this code doesn't work. My question specifically is why doesn't my courses hashmap populate with this code.

Prerequisites is an array in this form [[0,1][0,3][4,5][6,7]] and if I print my variables for pre and post they print what I expect

But I'm trying to turn courses into an adjacency matrix like this {0: [1,3], 4: [5], 6: [7]}
and instead it just prints an empty set every time

```
class Solution {
    fun canFinish(numCourses: Int, prerequisites: Array<IntArray>): Boolean {
        val courses = HashMap<Int, MutableList<Int>>().withDefault{ mutableListOf<Int>() }
        
        for ((pre, post) in prerequisites){
            courses[pre]?.add(post)
        }
        print(courses)
      
        return false
    }
}
```

```
stdout: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `[]` does not give you the default value

From the [docs of `withDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-default.html):

> This implicit default value is used when the original map doesn't contain a value for the key specified and a value is obtained with Map.getValue function

If you want to get the default value, you need to use `getValue` instead of the index operator.

Using the index operator, you would just get `null` and because of the the null-safe operator, the `add` operation would not even be executed.

If you take a look at [the relevant source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6a670dc5f38fc73eb01d754d8f7c158ae0176ceb/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kt#L75), you can see that the funxtionality `get` is not changed when using `.withDefault` but only `getOrImplicitDefault` returns the default value.

#### Getting the default does not set anything

Furthermore, when accessing `courses.getValue(pre)` in the loop, the `Map` will be empty. Because of the `withDefault`, it will return a `MutableList` where you can add elements but getting such a list and adding elements to it will not add the list to the `Map`. Reading and accessing an element does not insert it.

#### Simple solution

If you want to make sure the element is present in the `Map`, you can use `courses[pre]=course.getValue(pre)` before reading `courses[pre]?`:

```kotlin
class Solution {
    fun canFinish(numCourses: Int, prerequisites: Array<IntArray>): Boolean {
        val courses = HashMap<Int, MutableList<Int>>().withDefault{ mutableListOf<Int>() }
        
        for ((pre, post) in prerequisites){
            courses[pre] = courses.getValue(pre)
            courses[pre]?.add(post)
        }
        print(courses)
      
        return false
    }
}
```

If the entry is set already, it will be set to itself (no change) and if it isn't set, it will be set to the default value (empty list).

Answer (score 1):

dan1st's answer covers it - your default list is just *returned*, not *put and returned*, so it's not part of the map - but here's a different take to get that functionality:

```
val courses = HashMap<Int, MutableList<Int>>().run {
        withDefault{ key ->
            mutableListOf<Int>().also { put(key, it) }
        }
    }
```

So basically using the `withDefault` wrapper, using `run` so the map is `this` in the default value function, so you can add your list to the map before returning it. Then when you call `courses.getValue(69)` you'll get back a list that's already been inserted into the map

If you like, there's also a function that'll do this grouping for you, `groupBy`

```
val nums = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(0,1),
        intArrayOf(0,3),
        intArrayOf(4,5),
        intArrayOf(6,7)
    )

val groups = nums.groupBy(keySelector = { it[0] }, valueTransform = { it[1] })
println(groups)

>> {0=[1, 3], 4=[5], 6=[7]}
```